# Problem connect to SQL server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sql-server-2012

I try to connect from webpart to database server. Error happen in the line:

> conn.Open()
>
> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deploy the assembly of the web part to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), configure full trust for the application in the web config, or create a custom trust, that allows this kind of database interaction.

I suggest you to read the following articles to get a deeper insight into the Codes Access Security:

[Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services and Code Access Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916855.aspx)

[Code Access Security and SharePoint 2007 Web Parts](https://store.bamboosolutions.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10405)

Comment: I'm using Visual Webpart so there is no web config. What is the instead solution to trust for app.

Comment: Web.config is always there in the root of the SharePoint web application in IIS.

Comment: The typical path where you should find the web.config file is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\[your web app name]